# Dependence of Butler-Volmer equation on n for multiple transferred electrons

Tags: physical-chemistry, electrochemistry

I was working on an exercise sheet regarding the RDE results of an irreversible electrochemical reduction, with n transferred electrons. In it, we had to plot the Koutecky-Levich plot at different potentials, and as a result, it was deduced that n=4 electrons were transferred (probably the oxygen evolution half-reaction).

In another task, we had to estimate the rate constant of the reaction. The following relation is known for the reduction regarding the rate constant in terms of overpotential:

$k_{f}=k_{0}e^{\frac{-\alpha F(E-E^{0})}{RT}}$

Strictly speaking, this is valid for one electron processes, but I don't know for certain. Bard and Faulkner gives the general expression as:

[image]

My professor as (note it should be reduction not oxidation and a minus in the exponential, z=n):

[image]

Anyways, is n incorporated in this expession or not? I got $k_{f}$ from the Koutecky-Levich plot and need to calculate $k_{0}$. And if I used the version that incorporated n, my values would be in the range of $10^{-20} s/m$, which imo is too small, without the n around $10^{-8} s/m$, which seems more reasonable.

Similarly, to calculate the Tafel slope, Bard and Faulkner gives us for multistep electron exchanges with n>1:

[image]

Where n is the whole of the electrons transferred (in my case, n=4), f=F/RT. Note that n does *not* appear in the exponential term, only in the pre-exponential term. We then would need to neglect the oxidation current and calculate the Tafel slope. However, in my lecture, n appeared in the pre-exponential term and in the exponential term.

[image]

So, which one is correct for determining the Tafel slope? I would go with the textbook, although I am a bit lost here.

Comment: Is the question to determine the Tafel slope or the charge transfer coefficient? The Butler-Volmer equation does not include 'n' in the exponential term, the inclusion by some authors is incorrect and is a consequence of some multi-electron transfers showing this behavior (actually if you work out the individual reactions and write the total kinetic expression it might appear). The Tafel equation is purely empirical, so you just need to obtain how much the current changes per the potential and don't need to correct for the number of electrons.

Comment: It is to determine the Tafel slope, the charge transfer coefficient is 0.4

Comment: You would have to write the reaction as a set of 1 electron transfers and get the total kinetic expression like this (for which you need the standard reduction potential of each reaction and the charge transfer coefficient for each reaction or some other information on the reaction and, then see what the resulting Tafel slope is.

Comment: Note that for cases of math formulas taken from Wikipedia pages, one can click to edit link for a page section, copy  `<math>MathJax expression</math>` from there and paste it with <math>  replaced by single/double dollar. // Like `<math>j = j_0\frac {zF} {RT} (E-E_{\rm eq})</math>` converted to `$$j = j_0\frac {zF} {RT} (E-E_{\rm eq})$$`  displayed as $$j = j_0\frac {zF} {RT} (E-E_{\rm eq})$$

Comment: I just checked the Tafel slope for the experiment. It is 149 mV/decade, which would be consistent with the calculated Tafel slope, with alpha=0.4 and no "n" appearing in the formula (147 mV/decade).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Strictly speaking, this is valid for one electron processes, but I don't know for certain. Bard and Faulkner gives the general expression as:

From a theoretical point of view, Butler-Volmer kinetics apply *only* to a one-step, one-electron transfer. The B-V equation may be derived by extending Eyring's theory to electrochemistry. Your equation seems to be extracted from the second edition of Bark & Faulkner's bible, but I think the first one has this derivation.

From a practical point of view, if you have the *academic* electrochemical reaction:

$$ \ce{O + ne^- <=> R} \tag{1} $$

nothing stops you from writing the current density of this reaction as follows

$$ j = j_0 \left\{\exp\left(-\frac{\alpha nF}{RT}\eta\right) - \exp\left[\frac{(1 - \alpha)nF}{RT}\eta\right]\right\} \tag{2} $$

where the exchange current density is

$$ j_0 = \color{red}{n} F k_\mathrm{c}^{1 - \alpha}  k_\mathrm{a}^{\alpha} c_R^\alpha c_O^{1 - \alpha} \tag{3} $$

by just adding $n$ on the exponential terms. The reason to add $n$ is to have *thermodynamic consistency*. Once you set $j=0$ to zero, you recover Nernst's equation. If you do not put that $n$, you will obtain the following expression

$$ E^\text{eq} = E^\circ - \frac{RT}{F} \ln \left(\frac{c_R}{c_O}\right) \tag{4} $$

which is a typical mistake that makes you lose points in a chemistry exam. You may want to visit Chapter 8 of Newman's book (third edition) for more information about these equations

To conclude, it would be a conceptual mistake to not include the $n$.

> Similarly, to calculate the Tafel slope, Bard and Faulkner gives us for multistep electron exchanges with n>1:

That part of the chapter is a big dense, so I summarize it to you. Eq. (3.5.11) applies to a generic mechanism of $n$ electrochemical steps, in which:

- $n - 1$ of those steps are in equilibrium.
- $1$ is not, because it is supposed to be so slow, the so-called RDS.

The resulting current density is Eq. (3.5.11). This equation doesn't have the B-V fashion, because the concentrations still multiply the exponential terms. You need a bit more algebra to arrive at the final expression.

The last equation you posted, is equivalent to my Eq. (2), but still doesn't have the B-V fashion, because the concentrations multiply the exponential terms. The $\color{red}{n}$ you see there has to do with Eq. (3), belonging to the expression of $j_0$, plus lumping the cathodic and anodic rate constants into one, named $k^0$ by your professor.

To conclude, the equation from Bard & Faulkner refers to the general $n$-electron mechanism, whereas the equation from your professor refers to a general B-V kinetics for a *multiple*-electron transfer taking place in *one* step. Also, your professor likes the old convention, because the anodic reaction contributes to $j > 0$ and the cathodic reaction contributes to $j < 0$. Eq. (2) in this answer has the opposite convention, which was taught to me to be the one that prevails these days (with the exception in corrosion studies).

Comment: That's true, I believe n should be included. However, from the raw data we obtained, the inverse Tafel slope is 6.6 dec/V, which means the Tafel slope is 149 mV/dec. This would be in theory consistent with the expression (-2.303RT/aF), where a=0.4, like given in the exercise sheet. If I apply n=4 to the equation, the calculated result does not match the experimental evidence

Comment: @Mäßige You may consult that to your professor. I would like to point out that your Tafel's slope then has a more sublte meaning. It is that which belongs to the RDS in a 4-step electrochemical mechanism. Thus, you cannot associate it to the OER.

Comment: Ahh okay so you are saying that even though four electrons are transferred in total, the kinetics are limited by that RDS (whichever of the four steps it might be) and thus appears as around 140 mV/dec like a one step reduction?

Comment: And that should also be why the rate constant also appears in the order of magnitude of one step electron transfers

Comment: @Mäßige Yes. Since all the other steps are in equilibrium, they contribute *zero* to the current density. Only the RDS step has a Tafel's slope. In any case, there is more algebraic work to do in Eq. (3.5.11). IMO, I doubt that your professor wanted you to apply this general $n$-electron transfer mechanism. If you make sure, then you can tell me, and I can give further remarks.

Comment: Okay thanks a lot for your insight.

Comment: @Mäßige I realized another thing. Those $n$ electrochemical steps work for reactions of the type $\ce{O + ne^- <=> R}$. If you are sure that the reaction was $\ce{O2(g) + 4H^+(aq) + 4e^- <=> 2H2O(l)}$ (in acid medium), then I have my doubts, because it doesn't have that form. It is not evident how you would write the OER as a series of $4$ electrochemical steps.

Comment: @Mäßige E.g., the approach would work for reactions such as $\ce{Cr^{3+}(aq) + 3e^- <=> Cr(s)}$, but not for $\ce{Hg2SO4(l) + 2e^- <=> 2Hg(l) + SO4^{2−}(aq)}$.

Comment: Then it probably is not the OER. The sheet says that the reaction is of the form A(n+) + n e = B